# laravel 8 TDD $response->assertSessionHasNoErrors() is not working

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

The `Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse::assertSessionHasNoErrors()` isn't working as I would expect it to.

I have something like this in my code:

```php
$response = $this->post('account/project/create', $array);

$response->assertStatus(200); // FAILS
$response->assertStatus(500); // PASSES
$response->assertSessionHasErrors(); // FAILS
$response->assertSessionHasNoErrors(); // PASSES
```

As you can see, the `POST` returns a `500`, but `assertSessionHasErrors` does not fail. I would expect it to fail and return the exception message. I do not want to skip over exceptions by using `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()`.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after I posted this, I read that `assertSessionHasErrors` is only for validation errors. I use it often in unit tests so the change confused me a little.

For feature tests, you should just use `$response->assertStatus(200)` or `$response->assertSuccesfull()` and then you'll be given a stack trace if there is an exception.

This is pretty obvious, but I decided to leave my question up as I've been banging my head against the wall about it for more than an hour.  I did not want to skip over exceptions by using `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()`.